# React - Last list element removed when deleting from the middle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a list composed of an `<input>` field as well as a delete button, for each item. I also have an `Add item` button near the list so the user can add new entries.

I am encountering an issue when trying to delete a certain item from the list.
For example:
**The initial list**

| index | input-value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | d |
| 5 | e |

**After deleting the item at index 3**

| index | input-value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 4 | c |
| 5 | d |

As you can observe, the right item is deleted, but the contents are somehow shifted from their initial place and it appears like the last item is always deleted.

I can't figure it out what am I doing wrong.

Here is the parent component:

```
export default function ListPage() {
    const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);

    const removeItem = (index) => {
        console.log(index);
        const list = Object.assign([], itemList);
        const updatedList = list.filter((object, i) => i != index);
        setItemList(updatedList);
        console.log(updatedList);
    };

    const addItem = () => {
        const updatedList = [...itemList, <ListElement />];
        setItemList(updatedList);
        console.log(updatedList);
    };

    return (
        <div className="list-page">
            <div className="list-page-title">
                <h2>Create your own List</h2>
                <br></br>
                <h4>Create your own list</h4>
            </div>
            <input
                className="title-input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter Title"
            />
            <div className="list-content">
                {itemList.map((data, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <ListElement
                                handleRemove={() => removeItem(index)}
                                index={data.index}
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>

            <button className="add-button" onClick={addItem}>
                <span className="list-page-button-icon">+</span>Add Item
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And here is the `ListElement` component:

```
export default function ListElement(props) {
    return (
        <div className="list-item">
            <input
                className="item-input"
                type="text"
                placeholder={props.index}
            ></input>
            <MdRemoveCircleOutline
                className="remove-button"
                onClick={props.handleRemove}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I have added a key and now all the inputs after the one that is being deleted are being emptied of any text. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please create a sandbox with your code. you can also copy paste full code here with imports so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `removeItem` function, you don't need to do `const list = Object.assign([], itemList);`; which is messing the order of how the list is stored and rendered.
You already have access to the entire list in the `itemList` variable you defined before.

So, instead of

```
const removeItem = (index) => {
    console.log(index);
    const list = Object.assign([], itemList);
    const updatedList = list.filter((object, i) => i != index);
    setItemList(updatedList);
    console.log(updatedList);
  };
```

So, instead of

```
const removeItem = (index) => {
  const updatedList = itemList.filter((object, i) => i != index);
  setItemList(updatedList);
};
```